# .htaccess rewrite only if file/folder doesn't exist bug

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to make .htaccess rewrite only if a file or folder doesn't exist, I got that part down with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php?var=$1 [QSA,L]
```

However I am running into an issue where if I go to https://server/nonexistentfolder/secondnoneexistentfolder it will display index.php as if it was in that second non existent folder, which would then break all the links in the html document. How can I make index.php rewrite as if it was in the root directory?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please do mention which urls need to be served by index.php and which one should be served by other rules? By which we can get better picture of your question, thank you.

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry if this isn't clear but all files, directories, and symlinks auto normal. If they do not exist they are then rewritten to index.php?var=

Comment: sure but why you have `RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]` rule in your htaccess file? Could you please do let know here.

Comment: _"which would then break all the links in the html document"_ - it doesn't break them because of what happens on the server side, but because of what happens on the client side. That is the place, where relative URLs are combined with the base URL of the current document, to complete them to a full absolute one.